# Python Number in Range Not Working

Tags: python, range

```
def def range_test(num):
  if 1 < num < 550  :
    return( "{:d} is in range.".format(num))
  else:
    return("The number you entered is outside the range!")
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

My program just prints the "Enter a Number: " as its out put?
Can you figure out why?
Thanks!

Comment: Because your code never tries to print anything else?  You probably want to call range_test and print the result

Answer (score 1):

You haven't called the function. After the input, you need: `range_test(num)` to call the function. If you want to print the output you need to also print the return value.

The full program should be:

```
def range_test(num):
  if 1 < num < 550  :
    return( "{:d} is in range.".format(num))
  else:
    return("The number you entered is outside the range!")
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(range_test(num))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# manipulated code given below. it is working perfectly
def range_test(num):
   if 1 < num < 550  :
       return( "{:d} is in range.".format(num))
   else:
       return("The number you entered is outside the range!")

num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
s1=range_test(num)
print"%s"%(s1)
```